# How to fix alignment of text and image in header

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you help me construct a table header css here the icons are not aligned when viewing on a smaller view (1024). the problems i am facing is that when the text is not long enough the icon is on top while if it is a double liner. The icon is going bottom. my goal is even the text is a single or double liner the sorting image should be aligned

[table-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0eXq.png)

```
1<div class="globe-one-data-table">
  <div class="globe-one-data-table__inner">
    <div class="globe-one-data-table__list">
      <div class="globe-one-table-list">
        <div class="globe-one-table-list__thead">
          <div class="globe-one-table-list__tr"><input type="checkbox" style="">
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--1" style="
    width: 17%;
    /* overflow: auto; */
">Mobile Number<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon" style="
    /* float: right; */
"></div>
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--2" style="
    overflow: auto;
">Line Status<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon"></div>
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--3" style="
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
">Data Roaming<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon" style="
    float: right;
"></div>
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--4">
              <p class="sortTable">Account Number</p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon">
            </div>
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--5">
              <p class="sortTable">Employee Name</p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon">
            </div>
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--6">
              <p class="sortTable">Plan</p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon">
            </div>
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--7">
              <p class="sortTable">Amount To Pay</p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon">
            </div>
            <div class="globe-one-table-list__td globe-one-table-list__td--8">
              <p class="sortTable">Due Date</p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAZCAYAAAAIcL+IAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAADASURBVHgBxZMxDsMgDEUNysCYsWPGjhkZOUKP2iNkzMgxOjJ2o3ZkIhccr/kSiMDTk4wDQJda60Kj3/cwZsWRTBBNM4ODtTcmsY4qKGwtT94bjAnGxD9QsbWseBakMYGe0KyebQtcJ5LVMzQb4GGdGMpgJ8B9cVjRC+xiKIWK+YB+2TJvuh6q+GvZnHPZ40TQboAbTa2F+4X1sJ2gYT0bIX8zzTqCijXjXtGM0IGbPJjkB1mxAZnXBawg+JBvpeUHBKpJHH2E+X4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="sortIcon">
            </div><span class="acc-icon g1es-icon-bill billing-icon" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!---->
</div>


.globe-one-data-table {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  &__inner {
    background-color: white;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    padding: 3rem 1rem 3rem 3rem;
  }

  &__heading {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    padding: 0 20px 23px 20px;
  }

  &__filter {
    margin-top: 22px;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .form-element {
    width: 1;

    &:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    &__control {
      z-index: 1;
    }

    &__inner {
      position: relative;
    }

    &__control--icon {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 1%;
      padding-left: 5px;
      width: 45px;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: left;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }

  .globe-one-table-list {
    color: #244958;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;

    &__thead {
      display: none;
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }

    &__tr {
      display: block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-bottom: 2px #e4e8e9 solid;

      &--custom {
        padding-top: 6px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
      }

      &:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
    }

    &__td {
      padding: 7px 0;

      p {
        float: left;
        width: 0.5%;
        text-align: right;

        &:first-child {
          text-align: left;
        }
      }

      .globe-one-table-list__link {
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
    }

    &__label {
      font-family: $FSElliot-bold;
    }


    .error-message{
      width: 60rem;
      font-family: FS Elliot Pro;
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 22px;
      align-items: center;
      color: red;
      white-space: pre;
      text-align: left !important;
    }


    .sortIcon {
      height: 70%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024){
    .globe-one-data-table {

    .form-element {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 20px;

      &:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
      }

      &--search {
        max-width: 390px;
      }

      &--filter {
        max-width: 245px;
      }
    }

    .globe-one-table-list {
      &__thead {
        display: block;
      }

      &__label {
        display: none;
      }

      &__info {
        &__active {
          color: rgb(53, 193, 112);
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        &__mobileNo {
          font-weight: bold;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      }

      &__tr {
        display: table;
        width: 1%;
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 2px #e4e8e9 solid;

        input[type=checkbox] {
          margin: 2rem 1rem;
          width: 4rem;
          height: 2rem;
        }
      }

      &__td {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding 13px 0 11px 0;
        text-align: center;

        p {
          float: none;
          width: 1;
          text-align: left;
        }

        &--1 {
          width: 8%;
          padding-left: 1%;
        }

        &--1 {
          width: 17%;

        }

        &--2 {
          width: 12%;
        }

        &--3 {
          width: 10%;
        }

        &--4 {
          width: 14%;
        }

        &--5 {
          width: 15%;
        }

        &--6 {
          width: 9%;
        }

        &--7 {
          width: 14%;
        }

        &--8 {
          width: 10%;
        }

        .globe-one-table-list__link {
          margin-top: 0;
        }
      }

      &__label {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    .billing-icon {
      text-align: center;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size: 20px;
      display: table-cell;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code here.

Comment: Have you tried adding `display:inline-block` to the element?

Comment: Yeah, it will be of great help if you show us your code. But maybe try position absolute to your images and have right: 0;

Comment: wait a moment i will put the code

Comment: Without the code it will be hard to help, but you should definitely try applying this css rule `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: added code and styling btw its on scss

Answer (score 0):

in your table style, how about adding

```
table-layout:fixed
```

or

```
white-space:nowrap;
```